# How to compute exposure of an observation per year

Tags: sas

Hi everyone,

I come today with a problem that I can't resolve because I don't know where to start.

I would like to compute the total exposure of portofolio per specific year and per YearXmonth for the x last years.

For instance, if a contract starts in 1st January 2018 and ends in 15 november 2018, the contract has been exposed 11 months or 11/12years or 318 days for 2018. In january 2018, the contract has been exposed during 1 month, 1/12 years or 31 days, ...

In 2019, the contract has not been exposed at all.

Here is the information I have:

```
data have;
length ID Status $ 40;
input Id  Status $ Date_of_effect Date_Status ;

informat Date_of_effect Date_Status date9.;
format Date_of_effect Date_Status date9.;
infile datalines missover;
datalines;
1 Ongoing 05jul2015 05jul2015
1 Transformation 23Oct2014 05jul2015 
2 Death 07jan2017 02dec2018 
3 Finished 13feb2005 13feb2015
4 NoEffect 06nov2016 06nov2016
5 Cancellation 08MAR2014 19dec2018
6 Pending 21oct2018 21oct2018
;

run;
```

ID is the contract number

Status is the current status of the contract

Date_of_effect is the date where the contract is effective and begin to be exposed.

Date_Status is the date where the status has been changed.

For contracts with a Status "Noeffect", "Ongoing" or  "Pending", the date_of_effect equals the Status_date. For Ongoing and pending contracts I need to compute the exposure at the today date. So, I think that I need apply different rules for those contracts. For the other Status, the contract has been exposed between the Date_of_effect and Date_Status.

I want to create 3 differents tables where the first table summarizes the total exposure per year expressed in days month and year.

```
data Want_1;

input Year  Sum_Exposition_in_year Sum_Exposition_in_months Sum_Exposition_in_days;

infile datalines missover;
datalines;
2014
2015
2016
2017
2018
2019
;

run;
```

The second table is basically the same except that I introduce an additional segmentation:

```
data Want_2;

input Year month Sum_Exposition_in_year Sum_Exposition_in_months Sum_Exposition_in_days;

infile datalines missover;
datalines;
2014 1
2014 2
2014 3
2014 4
2014 5
2014 6
2014 7
2014 8
2014 9
2014 10
2014 11
2014 12
2015 1
2015 2
2015 3
2015 4
2015 5
2015 6
2015 7
2015 8
2015 9
2015 10
2015 11
2015 12
... ...
;

run;
```

And finally, I want to compute the exposure per contract for several years expressed in days and month.

```
data Want_3;
length ID Status $ 40;
input Id  Status $ Date_of_effect Date_Status Expo_days_2015 Expo_days_2016 Expo_days_2017 Expo_days_2018 Expo_days_2019 Expo_month_2015 Expo_month_2016 Expo_month_2017 Expo_month_2018 Expo_month_2019 ;

informat Date_of_effect Date_Status date9.;
format Date_of_effect Date_Status date9.;
infile datalines missover;
datalines;
1 Ongoing 05jul2015 05jul2015 179 365 365 365 153 6 12 12 12 6 
1 Transformation 23Oct2014 05jul2015 
2 Death 07jan2017 02dec2018 
3 Finished 13feb2005 13feb2015
4 NoEffect 06nov2016 06nov2016
5 Cancellation 08MAR2014 19dec2018
6 Pending 21oct2018 21oct2018
;

run;
```

I apologize if I haven't been clear enough. Don't hesitate to ask me more details.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you truly don't know where to start, what research have you done? I really don't mean to be snippy, but StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. We're happy to help you figure out specific issues, but if you need an entire program written to spec, you'll need to hire a developer.

Comment: Start with INTCK() which will determine the intervals in days. I have no idea how your WANT_2 would work since you only show two sets of values but a lot of variables. If you're not familiar with dates, this is a great reference: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/Working-with-Dates-and-Times-in-SAS-Tutorial/ta-p/424354?attachment-id=13253

Answer (score 0):

I almost achieved what I want but I'm stuck when it comes to create macro variable within a macro statement.

Thank you for having commented my post. I prefer to learn by myself to improve my knowledge in sas. :)

```
%let a=2015;
%let b=2019;


data Want_0 (drop=i) ;
set have;

array Expo_d_ (&a.:&b.) Expo_d_&a.-Expo_d_&b.;
array Expo_m_ (&a.:&b.) Expo_m_&a.-Expo_m_&b.;
if Status = "Ongoing" or Status="Pending" then
Date_Status=today();

do i=&a. to &b.;

Expo_d_(i) = max(0,min(mdy(01,01,i+1),Date_Status)-max(Date_of_effect,mdy(1,1,i)));
Expo_m_(i) = max(0,round((min(mdy(01,01,i+1),Date_Status)-max(Date_of_effect,mdy(1,1,i)))/(365.25/12),1));
end;
run;



%macro Do_stock;

proc sql noprint;

%do i=&a. %to &b.;
select sum(Expo_d_&i.) into: Expo_d_&i.
from work.Want_0;

select sum(Expo_m_&i.) into: Expo_m_&i.
from work.Want_0;
%end;                                                       

quit;
run;

%do i=&a. %to &b.;

%put Expo_d_&i.;
%put Expo_m_&i.;

%end;
%mend;
%Do_stock;

data Want_1 ( drop=i);
do i = &a. to &b.;

year= i;

Expo_day=&Expo_d_&i.;
Expo_month=&Expo_m_&i.;
end;

run;
```